# Cron Expression for SpringBoot Scheduled

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a requirement to run the job at every 30 minutes. However it is not suppose to be running on the 1 Jan and 25 Dec.

I have the following Cron expression which will be running for every 30 min. My question is how can I exclude couple days?

```
0 */30 * ? * MON-FRI *
```

Comment: I don’t believe this is possible simply using an expression string. However, you can also set the schedule programmatically.

Comment: I don't think this can be done by just a cron expression - this is too specific.
I think your best option is, to use your current cron expression as is and then check for 01/01 or 12/25 in your code and skip the execution if it is.